# What is the difference between these two SQL queries

Tags: sql, database, select, join

Is the second query a short form of the first? Is the second one doing something like an implicit JOIN?? They both return the same result...So I'd like to know which one is better to use. Using SQL Server 2008. Thanks for your answers.

First Query

```
SELECT b.columnOne, a.columnTwo
FROM tableA As a JOIN tableB As b ON a.id = b.id
```

Second Query

```
SELECT b.columnOne, a.columnTwo 
FROM tableA As a, tableB as b
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are identical. The second one is **not** using ANSI-standard join whereas the first one is.

Many, although not all, developers prefer the first version (ANSI-standard) as it keeps the `JOIN` logic in one place.  It allows **filter logic** to be kept in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

First query is the correct one.
Execution plan for second query is "translated" as the first one because engine understands that you're joining tables, so **in this case they are the same**.
Anyway when you use queries involving more than one related tables, you should always use `JOIN` syntax (because it was born for this) and avoid `WHERE`: with the latter, if engine is not able to translate to `JOIN` syntax, you could create huge queries because you multiply the number of records within each table (it's called cartesian product).

Comment: It's still valid JOIN syntax, Marco.  It's just a filtered cartesian product.

Comment: @JNK: yes, I know, but read the last part of my answer. I'm trying to tell OP he should use JOIN to join tables an WHERE to filter ;)

Comment: Yep I got that, Marco.  Just wanted to clarify there's no "translation" needed since this is a valid (if less clear and less used) `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Specifing the join separately (first form) is cleaner in my opinion. Then you can add your search criteria in the WHERE clause. But yes the two form are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Both the queries will return same results,

Take a look at the article on MS SQL Joins - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/102805/SQL-Joins

First query is the correct one and we can apply more filters on the condition using Joins - 
    Left Outer Join,
    Right Outer Join,
    Full Outer Join
etc